# Xpath: string functions not working fine

Tags: html, xml, string, xpath

I am new to xpath and have been wandering on the www for a long time to get the answer.
Found some links but couldn't get the answer.

I have the following xpath for a particular scenario and it is working fine

```
//li[contains(@class,'category_')]/a[contains(@href,'suits')]
```

Now when I tried to do the above thing using string function for learning purpose, it is not working. I tried the following xpath as the alternative.

```
//li[contains(@class,'category_')]/a[contains(@href,lower-case("SUITS"))]
//li[contains(@class,'category_')]/a[contains(@href,lower-case('SUITS'))]
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Please help.

Comment: Don't tell us that something "isn't working". Tell us how it failed. (-> Downvoting).

Comment: I think its understood why it is not working.
It is not working may be due to standards or some syntax, would I need to mention this thing then?

Comment: You've missed the point. Scanning your code to work out why it's wrong takes 20 seconds; if you gave us the error message it would only take 5 seconds. By not giving us the error message, you are wasting our time.

Comment: There was no error sir. Only it was not working without throwing an error. Anyways It is done now. Sorry If I did a mistake. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 1.0 was specified in 1999 and defines the `contains` function. [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) was specified in 2007 and [defines the `lower-case` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-lower-case). The latest version is [XPath 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/).
If you want to use the `lower-case` function then you need to use an XPath 2.0 or 3.0 implementation or alternatively an XQuery 1.0 or 3.0 implementation as XPath is basically a subset of XQuery.
I suspect that you are using an XPath 1.0 implementation and simply get an error that the function `lower-case` is not known.

Comment: Thanks for the enough info.